# MvvmCross + Xamarin.Forms "There is no implicit reference conversion..."

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, mvvmcross

I am following the official MvvmCross Xamarin.Forms tutorial ([link](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/tutorials/tipcalc/a-xamarin-forms-version)), and have the following error in Visual Studio:

> The type 'PriceWatch.Forms.UWP.App' cannot be used as type parameter
>   'TApplication' in the generic type or method
>   'MvxWindowsApplication'. There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'PriceWatch.Forms.UWP.App' to 'MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxApplication'.

The line of code that is highlighted is the following:

```
public abstract class PriceWatchApp : MvxWindowsApplication<MvxFormsWindowsSetup<App, FormsApp>, App, FormsApp>
{
}
```

I've double checked my code and the code from their official tutorial, and I can't spot any inconsistencies besides using "PriceWatch" namespace instead of "TipCalc"

Here is a screenshot of my Core, UI, and Xamarin.Forms UWP projects.

[image]

And here are some of the relevant code, if any of the other files in the solution need to be seen, just ask.

PriceWatch.Core.App.cs

```
namespace PriceWatch.Core
{
    public class App : MvxApplication
    {

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterType<IDatabaseService, DatabaseService>();

            RegisterAppStart<ProductsViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

PriceWatch.Forms.UI.FormsApp.xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace PriceWatch.Forms.UI
{
    public partial class FormsApp : Application
    {
        public FormsApp()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

PriceWatch.Forms.UWP.App.xaml.cs

```
using MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Uap.Core;
using MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Uap.Views;
using PriceWatch.Forms.UI;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace PriceWatch.Forms.UWP
{
    public sealed partial class App
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public abstract class PriceWatchApp : MvxWindowsApplication<MvxFormsWindowsSetup<App, FormsApp>, App, FormsApp>
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing to reference the `MainPage` of the UWP app, `public abstract class PriceWatchApp : MvxWindowsApplication<MvxFormsWindowsSetup<Core.App, FormsApp>, Core.App, FormsApp, MainPage>`

Comment: @FabriBertani Thanks, that was the solution.  As you can see on the tutorial I linked on their site, they have the wrong code for that line.  Their github example provided in the readme.txt after installing the MvvmCross.Forms package has the same working line that you showed.

Comment: Yes, sometimes the MvvmCross docs are outdated, but you could always check the [Playground](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/Projects/Playground) project to see the right implementations for any version. Having said that, you can make a PR to update the docs ;-)